# « Covariate shift » en français?

Tags: anglais, terminologie, science

Des idées sur comment traduire [*covariate shift*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Covariate-shift) en français?

Décalage covariant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... moi, dans ce domaine, ce sont les *covariables* que je décale et non pas le *décalage* que je fais covariant.

Pour moi, *covariate* est dans ton contexte un substantif et non un adjectif => je dirais, mais sans garantie "***Covariable décalée***" ou "*décalage de covariable*" et non "*décalage covariant*"

Ce terme de "*covariable décalée*" se retrouve d'ailleurs dans la littérature française des séries temporelles.

Comment: Si ce terme se retrouve dans la littérature des séries temporelles, pouvez-vous en fournir une source, de préférence avec une traduction anglaise ? Je me demande si ce n'est pas quelque chose qui correspond à un autre terme mathématique, "shifted covariant".

Answer (score 0):

Ce n'est pas évident qu'il y ait une traduction existante.

Ce [séminaire](https://ssc.ca/fr/modeles-prediction-methodes-denquete) utilise "décalage de covariable".

Ce [cours sur l'apprentissage artificiel](https://www.lri.fr/~antoine/Courses/ENST/Tr-histo-app-enst.pdf) le traduit par "changement co-varié".

Ce [livre](https://www.lri.fr/~antoine/Papers/2010/TdM-index-livre-AA.pdf) du même auteur utilise le terme "déplacement covarié".

Ce [travail de thèse](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01661470/document) qui porte sur le sujet a un résumé en français, mais le terme *covariate shift* est maintenu en anglais dans le texte français.

Dans tous les cas il s'agit d'usage unique sur le web.

Pour traduire, il faut comprendre si dans *covariate shift* le mot *covariate* est utilisé avec un sens adjectival ou un sens nominal.

Si le sens nominal de *covariate* est retenu, la traduction serait :

> Déplacement / changement / décalage de covariable

Si le sens adjectival est retenu, sur le modèle *covariate analysis* / analyse covariée, on peut construire :

> Déplacement / changement / décalage covarié

Cette question (usage adjectival ou nominal de *covariate*) étant principalement une question de mathématique et/ou d'anglais plutôt que de français, voilà à peu près tout ce que je peux en dire.

Comment: Désolé mais je ne vois vraiment pas une seule bonne raison pour traduire *covariate* (une covariable) en adjectif ou participe passé adjectivé ! Encore une fois ce n'est pas le décalage qui est *covariate* c'est la covariable qui est décalée!

Comment: Mes remarques dans le contexte du document soumis par user209974, car il est vrai que covariate peut, ailleurs prendre d'autres sens. (Mais jamais adjectivés à ce que je sache)

Comment: @aCOSwt surprenant... (1) je fournis pourtant une source universitaire de cette traduction (2) il me semble que ce n'est pas le seul cas de traduction de *covariate* employé comme adjectif en "covarié" ; cf. "covariate analysis" qui est souvent traduit par "analyse covariée" (3) en ayant passé un peu de temps à regarder le concept, je pense qu'il s'agit d'une bonne traduction du concept, étant d'abord un décalage ou changement entre les données de test et les données d'apprentissage ; le fait que ce décalage garde constant une probabilité conditionnelle est ce qui lui confère l'aspect covarié.

Comment: L'article suggéré par l'OP lie vers un "vrai" article de recherche : https://f1000research.com/articles/5-597/v1#ref-2 dans lequel on peut très clairement lire : "...The feature vectors describing these two sets are likely related but potentially different; and as such, **their covariates have shifted**." Encore une fois ce sont les covariables qui shiftent pas le décalage qui *covariate*. (Si tant est en plus qu'un *décalage covarié* cela puisse signifier quoi que ce soit)

Comment: OK - "their covariates have shifted" c'est clair que ça se traduirait par "leurs covariables se sont décalées." J'ai trouvé une autre source qui donne "décalage de covariable". Je vais l'ajouter. Cela dit le fait qu'un professeur d'université apparemment spécialiste se permette la traduction "covarié" me paraît tout de même notable !!

Comment: @aCOSwt voir réponse amendée (oublié d'ajouter le @ dans mon précédent commentaire).